# How to split bibliography for different sections?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, subdividing

Say I wish to have two references lists: one for all the citation within the main body, and another for all the citations within the Appendices. I'm using BibTeX. [`splitbib`](http://ctan.org/pkg/splitbib) and [`multibib`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multibib) don't seem to be the right way.

[`chapterbib`](http://ctan.org/pkg/chapterbib) seems to be very similar to what I need, but I couldn't find a working example, and I don't know how to adjust it to what I need (without splitting into different files). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could give the [`bibunits`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/bibunits) package a try. Assuming that (i) you wish to use the `plain` bibliography style in the main part of the document and the `unsrt` style in the appendix area and (ii) all bib entries are contained in a file named `mybib.bib`, the bibunits-relevant structure of your LaTeX file might look something like this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{bibunits}
\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\begin{bibunit}[plain]
... % with various citation commands strewn in
\putbib[mybib]
\end{bibunit}

\appendix % or whatever demarcation command you need to employ

\begin{bibunit}[unsrt]
... % with more citation commands
\putbib[mybib]
\end{bibunit}

\end{document}
```

If you only intend to use one bibliography style (say, `plain`) throughout, you could place the command

```
 \defaultbibliographystyle{plain}
```

in the preamble, freeing you from having to mention it in every `\begin{bibunit}` command. (Actually, `plain` *is* the default style in case nothing else is specified.)

Note that `bibunits` creates a separate `.aux` file for each bibunit you create, named `bu1.aux`, `bu2.aux`, etc. This means that you'll need to run BibTeX separately on each of these aux files.

Comment: I want to refer to another question which shows how to avoid latex creating a new bibliography chapter each time:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339883/25077

Answer (score 29):

Use [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) and its `refsection` feature. Note that entries cited both in the main text and the appendix will be included in both bibliographies.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\newrefsection

\section{First}

Some text \autocite{A01}.

\section{Second}

Some text \autocite{B02}.

\printbibliography[title={Main References}]

\appendix
\newrefsection

\section{App-First}

Some text \autocite{B02}.

\section{App-Second}

Some text \autocite{C03}.

\printbibliography[title={Appendix References}]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! is there an equivalent BibTex solution?

Comment: Is there a way to make cites in the appendix use the same references as in the previous sections such that Buthor is always cited as [2] and does not occur in the references of the appendix as it is already in the first references list? - Has it become clear what I mean?

Comment: @FlorianL wouldn't `\newrefsection` after the first ref list do this?

Comment: @FlorianL (and Ran G.). You can do this with multibib in BibTeX. Citations that are cited in both bibliographies will always be cited according to the first bibliography to avoid repeating entries. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98681/166207) for how to do it or have a look at the multibib docs.