# Two Bibliographies: one for main text and one for appendix

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, appendices, subdividing

I have a manuscript in which has the following structure:

```
Main Text
Bibliography
Appendix
```

However, there are citations which are only cited in the appendix, and they show up in the main bibliography. I would like to split my Bibliography into two different sections, so that the structure of the paper would look like this:

```
Main Text
Bibliography for Main Text
Appendix
Bibliography for Appendix
```

I'm currently using bibtex and a single .bib file, and creating the bibliography with

```
\bibliographystyle {someBibStyleFile}
\bibliography {bibFileName}
```

I'm interested in a method to split my single bibliography into main bibliography and appendix bibliography with minimal changes to the rest of the document. 
I'm aware that `biblatex` is more powerful than bibtex, but I'm not prepared to make the switch before the deadline of this project. There are many related bibliography-with-multiple-sections type of questions, but I didn't see one that covers this case.

Comment: have a look at [Per-chapter bibliographies in biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87414)

Comment: Overleaf help guide with MWE here: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/multibib

Answer (score 35):

Here's a solution with the `biblatex` package. The following shows how to do it. *Make sure you run `bibtex` on all auxiliary files, all `*[0-9]-blx.aux` files.*

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{myrefs.bib}
@Book{Knuth:1990,
    author    = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    title     = {The {\TeX}book},
    year      = {1990},
    isbn      = {0-201-13447-0},
    publisher = {Addison\,\textendash\,Wesley},
}

@Book{Lamport:94,
    author    = {Lamport, Leslie},
    title     = {\LaTeX: A Document Preparation System},
    year      = {1994},
    isbn      = {0-021-52983-1},
    publisher = {Addison\,\textendash\,Wesley},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{myrefs.bib}
\begin{document}

\section{First}
    {\LaTeX} is aTuring-complete
    (procedural) markup language and
    typesetting processor~\parencite{Lamport:94}.


\printbibliography
\appendix
\section{Second}
\begin{refsection}
   The ultimate reference of {\TeX} is~\parencite{Knuth:1990}.
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

Comment: I was hoping for a solution that *didn't* use biblatex

Comment: @Joe Any reason why you don't want to use `biblatex`?

Comment: I have an old build of ubuntu with an old version of the package, and was hoping for a solution where I didn't have to manually grab the package and all of its dependencies.

Comment: @Joe Have you considered doing a proper full install of _TeX Live_?

Comment: Yes. I'm in process, across several machines and virtual machines.

Comment: w.r.t making sure we run bibtex on all the right files, What do the compile commands for this specific example look like?

Comment: You run `biblatex file.aux` for each auxiliary bibligraphy file `file`. In my experience the names are given by `file.aux`, where `file` is the basename of your `.tex` file. the other files are called `file[0-9]+-blx.aux` (`[0-9]+` for one or several digits).

Comment: I think you intended to write ``biblatex`` at the very top of your answer, NOT ``bibtex``, right?

Comment: @PatrickT No, I meant _bibtex_.

Comment: Apologies, I was trying to compile it with ``XeLaTeX``. I have successfully compiled it with ``PDFLaTeX`` and it looks just like your screenshot (a single ``.aux`` file was produced). But no luck with ``XeLaTeX``. Since I was interested in ``XeLaTeX``, I apparently hadn't tried with ``PDFLaTeX``.

Comment: I deleted the comment above where I claimed that I had tried with ``PDFLaTeX``, obviously not true. Problem came from having various shortcuts to compile with different engines and getting mixed up about which shortcut was calling which engine... sigh.

Comment: wrt making sure we run bibtex on all the right files, Is there a way to create a build profile in TeXnicCenter that will do this?  I would rather not have to run everything through the Command Prompt.

Answer (score 31):

with `multibib`you can define more than one bib.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{myrefs.bib}
@Book{Knuth:1990,
    author    = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    title     = {The {\TeX}book},
    year      = {1990},
    isbn      = {0-201-13447-0},
    publisher = {Addison\,\textendash\,Wesley},
}

@Book{Lamport:94,
    author    = {Lamport, Leslie},
    title     = {{\LaTeX}: A Document Preparation System},
    year      = {1994},
    isbn      = {0-021-52983-1},
    publisher = {Addison\,\textendash\,Wesley},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{latex}{\LaTeX-Literature}%  \citelatex, \nocitelatex, ...

\begin{document}

\section{First}
  \citelatex{Lamport:94} wrote \LaTeX.

\bibliographystylelatex{alpha}
\bibliographylatex{myrefs}

\appendix
\section{Second}
   The ultimate reference~\cite{Knuth:1990}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{myrefs}

\end{document}
```

with `\newcites{suffix}{heading}` you can define the special macros.
The example has to be run with

```
pdflatex <file>
bibtex <file>.aux
bibtex latex.aux
pdflatex <file>
```

every additional bib needs its own `bibtex` run and can have a different bibstyle:

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly. I like this solution because it needs no additional \begin \end.

Comment: Note that there is no mechanism to avoid having the same reference in both bibliographies. If you cite the same article in both sections, make sure to use the cite command from your first section, otherwise the reference will show up in your second bibliography (even though it will still be cited according to the number in the first bibliography)

Comment: Is it possible to define a Build Profile in TeXnicCenter that will run the four commands required to compile this file (pdflatex <file>, bibtex <file>.aux, bibtex latex.aux, pdflatex <file>), instead of having to run them in the Command Prompt?  I tried to export the LaTeX-->PDF profile and modify it to add the second bibtex line, but TeXnicCenter gave an error when I tried to import the modified *.tco file, saying that it expected a "makeIndexCommand" instead of a second "bibTexCommand".

Comment: It looks like this can't work with TeXShop (on macs), because we don't have a pdflatex style run?

Answer (score 20):

You can use the `bibunits` package and structure your document as follows

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{bibunits}

\defaultbibliography{<bib-file>}
\defaultbibliographystyle{<preferred bib style>}

\begin{document}
\begin{bibunit}
Main Text
\putbib
\end{bibunit}

\begin{bibunit}
Appendix
\putbib
\end{bibunit}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is not clear to me how do you put the two different bibliographys as requested. As is, this seems to print the same biblio in two different places.

Comment: This is the standard way `bibunit` works, `\putbib` just prints a list of references for the `\cite` commands in the current unit.

Comment: this simply does not work for me

Comment: Forgot to mention that it creates separate bu*.aux files that need to be compiled with bibtex.

Comment: Is it possible to continue numbering between bibliographies so that the second bibliography picks up where the first left off?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the answers here is that the the choice is not really automatic: one needs to either use different commands/bib files, and even in that case duplicated items between main body and references are not removed. Here is a different solution for `biblatex`, which combines `filters` and `refsegment`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=trad-alpha]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{myrefs.bib}
@Book{Knuth:1990,
    author    = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    title     = {The {\TeX}book},
    year      = {1990},
    isbn      = {0-201-13447-0},
    publisher = {Addison\,\textendash\,Wesley},
}

@Book{Lamport:94,
    author    = {Lamport, Leslie},
    title     = {\LaTeX: A Document Preparation System},
    year      = {1994},
    isbn      = {0-021-52983-1},
    publisher = {Addison\,\textendash\,Wesley},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{myrefs.bib}
\defbibfilter{appendixOnlyFilter}{
  segment=1 % Segment 1 will be chosen to be the one in appendix
  and not segment=0 % Default segment is 0
}

\begin{document}

\section{Main Body}
{\LaTeX} is aTuring-complete (procedural) markup language and typesetting processor~\cite{Lamport:94}.

\printbibliography[segment=0]
\appendix
\newrefsegment %% <== increases the segment number (0 by default)

\section{Appendix}
The ultimate reference of {\TeX} is~\cite{Knuth:1990} and \cite{Lamport:94}, which should NOT be cited in this section.
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,filter=appendixOnlyFilter]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to simply compile the body and the appendix separately, and then append them on the back end. A basic script to do this would look like:

```
latex body.tex
bibtex body.aux
latex body.tex
latex body.tex
dvips -P pdf body.dvi
ps2pdf body.ps

latex appendix.tex
bibtex appendix.aux
latex body.tex
latex body.tex
dvips -P pdf appendix.dvi
ps2pdf appendix.ps    

gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -sOutputFile=main.pdf body.pdf appendix.pdf
```

In this situation, you would need to surround your appendix.tex with appropriate preamble, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`.

The last command (appending via Ghostscript) is taken from the second-ranked answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507766/merge-convert-multiple-pdf-files-into-one-pdf). You need to run `latex` at least thrice, as explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53235/why-does-latex-bibtex-need-three-passes-to-clear-up-all-warnings).

A streamlined script that I wrote (and regularly use), and which you can run from your Linux terminal, is available on GitHub [here](https://github.com/tyleransom/bash-scripts/blob/master/combiner). It has a few more bells and whistles (syntax checking, deletion of temporary LaTeX compilation files, etc.). The basic syntax is `combiner body.tex appendix.tex master.pdf`.