# Two bibliographies with repeated entries within one article

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, journal-publishing, multibib

I use the following code to generate a paper with its supplemental material. The number of the 3rd in-text bibliography entry in the main text is obviously incorrect, very possibly because of its appearance in the supplementary part. For certain reasons, I don't want to use bibunits. How can we avoid this? Thanks.
[image]

```
\documentclass[prl,twocolumn]{revtex4-1}
%\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\title{My Title}
\author{my name}
\affiliation{Somewhere}

\begin{abstract}
my abstract
\end{abstract}
\maketitle

\textit{Introduction.---}%
We have many\cite{Giuliani2005SM} things\cite{Hanamura1970SM} to say\cite{Laikhtman2001SM}.

\begin{thebibliography}{99}%
    \bibitem{Giuliani2005SM} 
    G.F. Giuliani and G. Vignale, 
    \textit{Quantum theory of the electron liquid} (Cambridge University Press, 2005).

    \bibitem{Hanamura1970SM}
    E. Hanamura, 
    J. Phys. Soc. Jpn. {\bf 29}, 50 (1970).

    \bibitem{Laikhtman2001SM}
    S. Ben-Tabou de-Leon and B. Laikhtman, 
    Phys. Rev. B {\bf 63}, 125306 (2001).

\end{thebibliography}

%Start Supplemental Material

%%%%%%%%%% Merge with supplemental materials %%%%%%%%%%
%\newpage
\onecolumngrid
%\newpage
{
    \center \bf \large 
    Supplemental Material\vspace*{0.1cm}\\ 
    \vspace*{0.0cm}
}
\twocolumngrid  

\section{A section}\label{App:section}
haha\cite{Laikhtman2001SM}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

    \bibitem{Laikhtman2001SM}
    S. Ben-Tabou de-Leon and B. Laikhtman, 
    Phys. Rev. B {\bf 63}, 125306 (2001).

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: have you tried `multibib`?

Comment: Because I didn't read the question properly I answered a solution with `bibunits` -- sorry for this. Deleted it. Anyway the first sentence is still correct: "I think this will help you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98660/two-bibliographies-one-for-main-text-and-one-for-appendix ."