# Creating multiple bibliographies from different *.bib files in one document, some using \nocite{*} some not

Tags: bibtex

**I'm trying to do the following:**

My thesis has an extensive part about my literature searching process. Basically I would like to describe all the steps I made in order to find my final 10 papers on which I then base my literature research.
The algorithm goes something like this:

- combine keyword 1, 2 and 3 => search for papers => show resulting papers List AAA
- add keyword 4 => search list AAA with keyword 4 => show resulting list BBB
- add keyword 5 => search list BBB with keyword 5 => show final list CCC

**Now the latex part:**

I would like to show a list of all papers in list AAA, BBB and CCC. 
As basis I'm using mendeley. From here I can export a *.bib file with all papers of AAA, BBB and CCC.

Lists AAA, BBB and CCC should be showing **ALL entries** in their *.bib files, also the ones which remain un-cited in the text before.

**While** the original bibliography (NOT AAA, BBB or CCC) should keep on showing only the entries, which where actually cited in the text.

Based on these AAA.bib, BBB.bib and CCC.bib files I would like to create some sort of additional bibliography lists all the way back in the appendix.
This should not influence my original Bibliography section, which will stay in place.

**So now I'm wondering:**

- how can I simply add these lists in the appendix?
- can latex make different bibliographies parallel to each other?
- maybe anyone has a better idea on how to do this?

Thanks a lot in advance! :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you see [Two Bibliographies: one for main text and one for appendix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98660)?

Comment: @egreg thanks for the hint! I looked into and it's definitely a stept forward, but I'm still not sure how to switch between showing only cited entries in the original bibliography and showing all containing entries in the AAA, BBB and CCC bibliographies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found a way to do this and would like to post my solution here for future reference and for everyone who is working with **mendeley** and runs into similar questions.

Anyway the solution turned out to be quite simple:
- create a new folder in mendeley with the papers/ article you want to list als reference
- mark them all (ctl+a)
- open a word doc and paste it there
- now you have a full list in **text form**

!!! make sure you do this all the way in the end when you are sure that the info within your references (e.g. year, author, ect) won't change anymore.
If it does change then you simply have to repeat the task.... and done.

Hope this can be of help for someone :)