# Multibib fails to show a second bibliography in the appendix

Tags: bibliographies, multibib

I am using `multibib` and `natbib` together to get two different bibliographies (one for the main text and one for the appendix). Here is an example code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{multibib} 
\newcites{apndx}{References}
\begin{document}

First paper to cite: \cite{X1}
\bibliographystyle{ecca}
\bibliography{XXX}

\appendix

Cite a paper in the appendix \citeapndx{X2}

\bibliographystyleapndx{ecca} 
\bibliographyapndx{XXX}


\end{document}
```

However, the second bibliography does not show up, and the citation in the appendix only gives a "?". I looked up in the `multibib` manual and in other similar questions, but I do not get where the error is.

UPDATE 1 
This happens even though I run the bibtex file twice. Here is the `log` file:

```
Process started: /Library/TeX/texbin/bibtex "prova".aux

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2016)
The top-level auxiliary file: prova.aux
The style file: plain.bst
Database file #1: myrefs.bib

Process exited normally 

Process started: /Library/TeX/texbin/bibtex "prova".aux

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2016)
The top-level auxiliary file: prova.aux
The style file: plain.bst
Database file #1: myrefs.bib

Process exited normally
```

UPDATE 2:
I think the problem is that my TexStudio does not run the `sec.aux` file which generates the link to the second bibliography. I followed the steps of this link https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Tips%20and%20Tricks/ and created a `.cwl` and added it to TexStudio Completion but it still does not work.

Comment: Hi, I use TexStudio and I just hit "Build and View" to compile it (I hit the button multiple times). Does the example code work on your end? Thank you

Comment: Please have a look to the answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98681/16550 Possible duplicate? you need two bibtex runs, one for each bibliography!

Comment: I am hitting the compile button twice, but it does not work. I tried the code in that thread, but it didn't work as well. In particular the first bibliography in that example does not work. The `newcites` command seem not to work fine. Does my code work on your latex compiler? Thank you.

Comment: I added the log file showing that I always run the bibtex twice. Still the bibliography does not work.

Comment: You need to run `bibtex prova.aux` and then `bibtex sec.aux` or whatever. Can't you do it on the command line if it is tricky persuading your editor? Or you can use something like `latexmk` if you want a single run to hit.

Comment: The `.cwl` thing just gets you auto-completion of macros when editing. It is irrelevant to compilation. You need to look at 'Correct Compilation (platform independent)' or, if that doesn't work for you on Windows, the alternative batch-file method explained under 'Correct Compilation (Windows)'. At least, that's what the instructions say. I'm just reading them and repeating them back to you. (I don't use TeXStudio or Windows and know nothing of batch files. Though the cross-platform command looks plausible enough.)

Comment: could you please explain me how to do the 'Correct Compilation (platform independent)'? I didn't understand how that works. How do I set the bibliography command to `bibtex ?*.aux`?

Comment: Thank you so much! Just a last question: it does not work when I use citeapndx in a `caption` to a figure/table. Do I need to load another package?

Comment: Your reputation points are now high enough you are allowed to vote up helpful answers. Please consider to do this with the answer below. It is the way to say "Thank You" here ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `multibib` results after the first compile run of file `mwe.tex` with `pdflatex` (or in your case compiling with TeXStudio) in two new files `mwe.aux` and `apndx.aux`. Both `.aux` files needs to be run with `bibtex`.  TeXStudio does the run with `bibtex` for file `mwe.aux`, for `apndx.aux` you need to do it by your own. Just run the command `bibtex apndx` in a windows terminal. 
After that you can compile two times with TeXStudio to get the resulting PDF.

To get command `\citeapndx` be run in a caption of a figure (your question in the comments) you need to use command `\protect` like (same for a `\section`):

```
  \caption{In figure caption \protect\citeapndx{Johnson2000}}
 %                           ^^^^^^^^
```

So with the following file `mwe.tex` (package `filecontents` is only used to have both bib files and the tex code in one compiling MWE):

```
% needs:  bibtex apndx
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{Creighton2006,
  author    = {Creighton, Oliver and Ott, Martin and Bruegge, Bernd},
  booktitle = {Requirements Engineering, 14th IEEE International Conference},
  isbn      = {0769525555},
  pages     = {109--118},
  publisher = {IEEE},
  title     = {{Software cinema-video-based requirements engineering}},
  url       = {http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs{\_}all.jsp?arnumber=1704054},
  year      = {2006},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{apndx.bib}
@article{Johnson2000,
  author  = {Johnson, W Lewis and Rickel, Jeff W and Lester, James C},
  journal = {International Journal of Artificial Intelligence in Education},
  number  = {11},
  pages   = {47--78},
  title   = {{Animated pedagogical agents: face-to-face interaction in 
              interactive learning environments}},
  volume  = {Internatio},
  year    = {2000},
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{multibib} 
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcites{apndx}{References in Appendix}


\begin{document}

First paper to cite: \cite{Creighton2006}
\bibliographystyle{ecca}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\appendix

Cite a paper in the appendix \citeapndx{Johnson2000}

%\section{In the appendix \protect\citeapndx{Johnson2000}} % <===========
\begin{figure}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}
  \caption{In figure caption \protect\citeapndx{Johnson2000}} % <=======
  \label{fig:example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\bibliographystyleapndx{ecca} 
\bibliographyapndx{apndx}

\end{document}
```

and the compiling chain (independent from TeXStudio):

- open a terminal window in Windows with pressing windows start key and `R`, then type `cmd`, press enter
- move to the directory where you have your tex code and the bib file(s) with `cd <directory path>`
- run command `pdflatex mwe` (resulting in two needed `.aux` files)
- run command `bibtex mwe`   (compiles `mwe.aux`)
- run command `bibtex apndx` (compiles `apndx.aux`)
- run command `pdflatex mwe` (resulting in files `*.bbl` and `*.blg`)
- run command `pdflatex mwe` (resulting in `pdf` file with bibliography)

If you are using an editor (TeXStudio, TeXnicCenter, ...) the editor can run `pdflatex mwe` and `bibtex mwe` for you, but not  `bibtex apndx`.  So run this command after the first compile run with TeXStudio in a windows terminal ...

After running the compile chain you get the following resulting pdf:

[image]