# Running a .aux file with bibtex

Tags: bibtex, texshop, multibib

I need to follow the following instructions to compile multiple bibliographies in the same document:

```
pdflatex <file>
bibtex <file>.aux
bibtex latex.aux
pdflatex <file>
```

I have this heading:

```
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{latex}{\LaTeX-Literature}%
```

I have opened the `latex.aux` file but TexShop does not allow me to compile it with Typeset. Can anyone help me?

The file is more or less like this:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[margin=52pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb} 
\usepackage[hang, small,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption} 
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{soul} 
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{latex}{References Supplementary Material}


\begin{document}

Text.... \cite{}.

\bibliographystyle{vancouver} 
\bibliography{mybib.bib} 


Text with \citelatex{}.


\bibliographystylelatex{vancouver} 
\bibliographylatex{mybib.bib} 


\end{document}
```

I was following the instructions here 
[Two Bibliographies: one for main text and one for appendix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98660/two-bibliographies-one-for-main-text-and-one-for-appendix/418387?noredirect=1#comment1046672_418387)

It says to run

```
pdflatex <file>
bibtex <file>.aux
bibtex latex.aux
pdflatex <file>
```

But I am not able to run `bibtex latex.aux` using TexShop.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example with bibliography ([MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thank you! Sure I just edited the question with the details

Comment: You do not need to open the `.aux` file in your editor. There should be a menu point to run BibTeX/a bibliography tool of your choice (F5?/Command-Shift-B?) when you have your main `.tex` file open. Your editor should automatically run the commands on the correct files.

Comment: Hi! Yes, Sure. You can run BibTex on the mail file. But the instructions say to run BibTex on the separate .aux file generated by the line 
       \newcites{latex}{References Supplementary Material}

And TexShop does not allow me to

Comment: No, TeXShop is perfectly able to choose the right file when you select BibTeX from the drop-down menu, keeping the main TeX file active.