# How set two bibliography in latex?

Tags: bibliographies

```
\newsection
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibliography{bibliography}{}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}       

\newsection
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography_ilustration}
\bibliography{bibliography_ilustration}{}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
```

But I got some error when I use `\cite{item_from_bibliography_ilustration}`

Comment: You might want to take a look at this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98681/184389 on how to use multibib to have several bibliographies in one document.

Comment: @KersouMan, OP isn't asking about having two ``.bib`` files in one bibliography, he's asking about **having two sections that each have their own bibliography**. The sections **shouldn't share the same bibliographie nor the same ``.bib`` file**.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the use of `multibib`. 
This package allows you, first, to print several bibliographies in your document and, second, to use several `.bib` files to do so.

An example is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@Book{Knuth:1990,
    author    = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    title     = {The {\TeX}book},
    year      = {1990},
    isbn      = {0-201-13447-0},
    publisher = {Addison\,\textendash\,Wesley},
}

@Book{Lamport:94,
    author    = {Lamport, Leslie},
    title     = {{\LaTeX}: A Document Preparation System},
    year      = {1994},
    isbn      = {0-021-52983-1},
    publisher = {Addison\,\textendash\,Wesley},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography_ilustration.bib}
@article{Olfati:2004,
  title   = {Consensus problems in networks of agents with switching topology and time-delays},
  author  = {Olfati-Saber, Reza and Murray, Richard M},
  journal = {IEEE Transactions on automatic control},
  volume  = {49},
  number  = {9},
  pages   = {1520--1533},
  year    = {2004}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{multibib}
    \newcites{secone,sectwo}{References for section 1, References for section 2}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

    \citesecone{Knuth:1990}

    \bibliographystylesecone{unsrt}       
    \bibliographysecone{bibliography}{}

\section{Section 2}

    \citesectwo{Olfati:2004}

    \bibliographystylesectwo{unsrt}
    \bibliographysectwo{bibliography_ilustration}{}

\end{document}
```

which gives you as a result:

[image: result_code]

However, by using `multibib` this way, you will have to run `bibtex` for each of your bibliographies:

```
bibtex secone
bibtex sectwo
...
```

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98681/184389) does the same thing using only one `.bib` file and several bibliography styles.