# Multiple bibliographies in Revtex 4.1

Tags: bibliographies, revtex

I am trying to merge my paper with the supplementary information to be posted on Arxiv.

Ideally, I would have two files, paper.tex and si.tex, each having its own bibliography. Then I would have a third file merged.text, with a preamble and two include statements (\include{paper.tex} and \include{ms.tex}.
I need to have two bibliographies, one for the paper, one for the supplementary information, all in one file.

However, nothing I tried seems to work with Revtex 4.1. I tried multibib, chapterbib packages, but they all give errors.

If I don't use any of these packages, just use \bibliography{refs.bib} at the end of both paper.tex and ms.tex and then include them in merged.tex then the bibliography just gets repeated, which is not what I want.

Could someone help?

Comment: This might help - https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98660

Comment: Revtex4.1 is depreciated, now revtex4.2 must be used. https://ctan.org/pkg/revtex