# Chapterwise bibliographies at the section level in ToC

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, subdividing

I use `chapterbib` and `bibtex` for my thesis (no `natbib`, as it interferes with the class file). The chapter wise bibliographies are listed at the chapter level in the ToC. How can I get it to position at the section level instead?

Comment: Does this help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44589/how-to-split-bibliography-for-different-sections?rq=1

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: The [manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/chapterbib) (§5) states that the `sectionbib` option is supposed to do so (`\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}`), but I haven't tested it.

Comment: @henrique Almost... It correctly adds a line at the section level, but also leaves the chapter entry.

Comment: Sorry, I had not seen you comment. The behavior you described: could it be due to not unough compiling (as when `latex` asks `Rerun to get cross-references right`)? Please, check if the answer solves your issue; if not, I'm afraid I haven't quite followed you: perhaps, you should edit your question then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**`chapterbib`**](http://ctan.org/pkg/chapterbib) package provides the `sectionbib` option aimed at putting bibliographies on section level in bookish (`book`, `report`...) documents. Check §5 of the [documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/chapterbib).

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{filecontents}{chap1.tex}
  \chapter{First Chapter}
  \section{A section}
  \blindtext
  \cite{book-full}
  \bibliographystyle{plain}
  \bibliography{xampl}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{chap2.tex}
  \chapter{Second Chapter}
  \section{Another section}
  \blindtext
  \cite{article-full}
  \bibliographystyle{plain}
  \bibliography{xampl}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\include{chap1}
\include{chap2}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

And a shot of the table of contents:

[image]

Comment: My sincere apologies... it was the university thesis class file that was inserting an additional toc entry at the chapter level. I've commented out that line and all's well. Thanks :)