# How to configure latex to put bibliography at end of each chapter when using subfiles?

Tags: bibliographies, chapters, subfiles

I'd like to have the bibliography of each chapter at its end. Here is an MWE of how I built my thesis:

I have a directory tree which looks like this:

```
|-main.tex
|-ref.bib
|--Ch1
|---ch1.tex
|--Ch2
|---ch2.tex
```

And I'm using `\subfiles` to build the document.

`main.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
    \subfile{Ch1/ch1.tex}
    \subfile{Ch2/ch2.tex}
% Experimenting with configurations of bibliography
%   \bibliography{ref}
\end{document}
```

`Ch1/ch1.tex`

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{Chapter 1}
    I am a reference from chapter 1.\citep{lamport1994latex}
    \bibliographystyle{agsm}
    \bibliography{ref}
\end{document}
```

`Ch2/ch2.tex`

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{Chapter 2}
    I am a reference from chapter 2.\citep{goossens1997latex}
    \bibliographystyle{agsm}
    \bibliography{ref}
\end{document}
```

`ref.bib`

```
@article{lamport1994latex
  title={LATEX user’s guide and reference manual},
  author={Lamport, Leslie},
  year={1994},
  publisher={Addison-Wesley, Reading, Massachusetts}
}
@book{goossens1997latex,
    title={The LATEX graphics companion: illustrating documents with TEX and PostScript},
    author={Goossens, Michel and Rahtz, Sebastian PQ and Mittelbach, Frank},
    volume={3},
    year={1997},
    publisher={Addison-Wesley Professional}
}
```

I've tried several possibilities of `\bibliography{ref.bib}` in the three files and none of them produced a desirable output, which would be as I expect: two bibliographies at all; one at the end of chapter 1 and one at the end of chapter 2, with only `lamport1994latex` in the first bibliography and only `goossens1997latex` in the second bibliograhy. Is this possible?

Comment: maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44602/36296 could help

Comment: Not sure if this works with subfiles: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130337/36296

Comment: In case you are free to switch to biblatex, there this actually quite easy to achieve with refsections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use another type of bibliography, e. g. putting it directly at the end of your chapter. Dividing your `ref.bib` shouldn't be that much work for not writing your thesis like in a pandemonium.

Version 1 (bibliography at the end of the part with a blank page in between):

main-v1.tex:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\include{one}
\include{two}
\end{document}
```

one-v1.tex:

```
    \chapter{One}
        \lipsum[1]\cite{lamport1994latex}
        \begin{thebibliography}{One}
            \bibitem [Lamport 1994]{lamport1994latex}Leslie Lamport: LATEX user’s guide and reference manual, Reading, Massachusetts 1994, Addison-Wesley.
        \end{thebibliography}
```

two-v1.tex:

```
    \chapter{Two}
        \lipsum[2]\cite{goossens1997latex}
        \begin{thebibliography}{Two}
            \bibitem [Goossens \textit{et al.} 1997]{goossens1997latex}Michel Goossens, Sebastian P. Q. Rahtz, Frank Mittelbach: The LATEX graphics companion: illustrating documents with TEX and PostScript, Vol. 3, 1997, Addison-Wesley Professional.
        \end{thebibliography}
```

Version 2 (bibliography directly at the end of the part):

main-v2.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\include{one}
\include{two}
\end{document}
```

one-v2.tex:

```
    \part{One}
        \lipsum[1]\cite{lamport1994latex}
        \begin{thebibliography}{One}
            \bibitem [Lamport 1994]{lamport1994latex}Leslie Lamport: LATEX user’s guide and reference manual, Reading, Massachusetts 1994, Addison-Wesley.
        \end{thebibliography}
```

two-v1.tex:

```
    \part{Two}
        \lipsum[2]\cite{goossens1997latex}
        \begin{thebibliography}{Two}
            \bibitem [Goossens \textit{et al.} 1997]{goossens1997latex}Michel Goossens, Sebastian P. Q. Rahtz, Frank Mittelbach: The LATEX graphics companion: illustrating documents with TEX and PostScript, Vol. 3, 1997, Addison-Wesley Professional.
        \end{thebibliography}
```

Note: You can't use `\chapter` in an article without defining it.
You can use `\part`, `\section`, `\subsection`, `\subsubsection`, `\paragraph`, `\subparagraph`.

I also recommend using the simple `\include` command instead of an additional package.

If you also sort your folders and files by type and origin/destination (e. g. graphics for theory, graphics from measured data, `tex` files in mainfolder, ...) with all titles at lowercase, you'll definitely will have a way better overview about your thesis and your work progress.