# Printed cited refs under "References" and then print all references under "Bibliography"?

Tags: biblatex

I'm doing a dissertation which has the requirements of printing a References section, of those resources which have been cited, and then a bibliography which includes all resources, cited or not.

I've tried this:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,citestyle=authortitle,url=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\bibliography{refs} <- and what does this do?
\addbibresource{project_references.bib}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}

\begin{document}
    \printbibliography

    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

But the \nocite{*} has an effect on both, regardless of where it is. Which defeats the point. I've been through numerous answers which include creating a boolean of "cited" and then trying to print those but nothing seems to work!!

I just want:

"References"
Yada yada... I've been cited!

"Bibliography"
Yada yada... I may not have been cited!

---

Taking the answer received this is what I have now, which is not working. All references are being printed in each section:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report} 
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,citestyle=authortitle,url=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\addbibresource{project_references.bib} 

\begin{refsection}
\chapter{Introduction}
\subfile{Introduction.tex}

\chapter{Literature Review}
\subfile{LiteratureReview.tex}

\chapter{Design}
\subfile{Design.tex}

\chapter{Implementation and Testing}
\subfile{Implementation.tex}

\chapter{Evaluation}
\subfile{Evaluation.tex}

\chapter{Conclusion}
\subfile{Conclusion.tex}

\printbibliography[title=Cited]
\end{refsection}

\printbibliography[title=References]

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title=Bibliography]
\end{document}
```

Don't know if it matters but I'm not using article, because I want chapters.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: In what situation would these sections be different? I mean: why adding a reference if not for citing it somewhere, thus indicating its usage?

Comment: Check out this answer:
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44589/how-to-split-bibliography-for-different-sections

You could adapt it to your case.

Comment: This is because we're strictly using the Harvard Referencing style. Not everything I've read that's useful has been included in this style. Plus I've read multiple resources for maybe one point, I don't fancy having a list of references for one point when I have a word limit.

Comment: Use my answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6967/how-to-split-bibliography-into-works-cited-and-works-not-cited, *but* omit `notcategory=cited` in the second `\printbibliography`.

Comment: I've tried this, and messed around with it and it just prints one or the other twice. At this moment I'm just going to print off one of them separately. I've tried moving \nocite{*} at the top like your answer, moving it in between printing, it gives me an error saying there's no back end and run Biber on it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{onlysome.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{refsection}
  \section{Foo}
  \cite{one}

  \section{Bar}
  \cite{two}

  \printbibliography[title=Cited]
\end{refsection}


\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title=All]

\end{document}
```

The first `\printbibliography` will only print the items inside that `refsection`, that is those that are cited.

Comment: This makes sense to me, and I've tried it. However it doesn't seem to work with subfiles. It's not printing the first references section at all.

Comment: What subfiles are those? Do you use `\input` or `\include` to include other files? Or are you using the package `subfile`?

Comment: I use the subfile package.

Comment: I meant the package `subfiles`. (I accidentally dropped an s.) I guess you do the same.

I see no reason why that would matter, but I tested with `subfiles` and it worked fine. Make sure the `refsection` environment goes around everything it should. If it still doesn't work I think an MWE is needed again.