# Multiple references and bibtex files

Tags: bibtex

I'd like to create a single latex file where I can add many bibtex files, (or only one but that has different sections.)

So for example, I'd ideally just want a document that looks like this:

```
Literature Review 1
[1] Author1, "MCMC sampling", 2015
[2] Author2, "Stochastic Gradient Descent", 2017

Literature Review 2
[1] AuthorA, "SIFT key point descriptors", 2018
[2] AuthorB, "HOG for pedestrian detection", 2012
```

Instead of how it usually looks like whenever I use references:

```
References
[1] Author1, "MCMC sampling", 2015
[2] Author2, "Stochastic Gradient Descent", 2017
[3] AuthorA, "SIFT key point descriptors", 2018
[4] AuthorB, "HOG for pedestrian detection", 2012
```

So far this has been my strategy:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\ComputerVision}{\chapter*}{\section*}{}{}
\patchcmd{\MachineLearning}{\chapter*}{\section*}{}{}

\begin{document}
\input{ComputerVision}
\input{MachineLearning}
\end{document}
```

ComputerVision.tex is the following file:

```
\renewcommand\refname{Computer Vision}

{\small
\bibliographystyle{ieee}
\bibliography{egbib_CV}
}
```

MachineLearning.tex is the following file:

```
\renewcommand\refname{Machine Learning}

{\small
\bibliographystyle{ieee}
\bibliography{egbib_ML}
}
```

egbib_ML.bib is:

```
@article{hash1,
  title={MCMC sampling},
  author={Author1},
  year={2015}
}

@article{hash2,
  title={Stochastic Gradient Descent},
  author={Author2},
  year={2017}
}
```

egbib_CV.bib is:

```
@article{hashA,
  title={SIFT key point detector},
  author={AuthorA},
  year={2018}
}

@article{hashB,
  title={HOG for pedestrian detection},
  author={AuthorB},
  year={2012}
}
```

The output that I get instead just looks like this (where everything repeats itself...):

```
Literature Review 1
[1] Author1, "MCMC sampling", 2015
[2] Author2, "Stochastic Gradient Descent", 2017
[3] AuthorA, "SIFT key point descriptors", 2018
[4] AuthorB, "HOG for pedestrian detection", 2012

Literature Review 2
[1] Author1, "MCMC sampling", 2015
[2] Author2, "Stochastic Gradient Descent", 2017
[3] AuthorA, "SIFT key point descriptors", 2018
[4] AuthorB, "HOG for pedestrian detection", 2012
```

Comment: With biblatex+biber you can e.g. use refsection to split your references.

Comment: Try the `bibtopic` package that lets you create multiple bibliographies in the same doc.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the [chapterbib](http://ctan.org/pkg/chapterbib) and [bibunits](http://ctan.org/pkg/bibunits) packages. Both packages let you create dedicated bibliographies for different parts of the document. Separately, have you consulted the posting [How to split bibliography for different sections?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44589/5001)