# bibliography at the end of each chapter

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

Good evening,

I need your help please because I spent so much time to make the bibliography at the end of each chapter but I fails till now. In fact, I'm writing my master-thesis of three chapters with different bibliography. So I define three bib files with different names (for ex `bibch1`, `bibch2`,`bibch3`) and inside each one I put the corresponding references. At the end of each chapter, I have written:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{apalike-fr}
\bibliography{bibch1} %bibch2 at the end of second chapter etc..
\markright{\MakeUppercase{Bibliographie}}
```

The main tex file is the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}           
\usepackage[english]{babel}         
\usepackage[dvips]{epsfig}              
\usepackage{amsmath}                    
\usepackage{amssymb}    

\begin{document}

\input{chapter1}

\input{chapter2}

\end{document}
```

Please can you help me by showing me what is the missing or I you can give me a simple example to overcome this problem. Thank you very much

Comment: Have you checked out all the related questions to the right?

Comment: Out of the box `latex`/`bibtex` don't support multiple bibliographies in a single document, there are a number of packages which facilitate this (https://www.ctan.org/topic/bibtex-multi) or you could look at [`biblatex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) which is similarly capable of producing multiple bibliographies.  [This answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17480/106162) or [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44602/106162) give a couple of examples with `bibtex`-based packages and of course you can consult documentation of relevant packages for further examples.

Comment: Assuming you are using `BibTeX`, here is another possible answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/300144 that uses the `chapterbib` package. Probably what is frequently overlooked in producing separate bibliographies is the need to run `BibTeX` on the `aux` file for each chapter.