# Different natbib bibliography for shared chapters and separate chapters

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I want to create an article in Latex with `natbib` and the following structure:

1. Introduction
2. Chapter 2
3. Chapter 3
4. Discussion

The article's references should have the following characteristics:

- Introduction and Discussion should "share" their reference list
- Chapter 2 and Chapter 3 should each have their own reference list (only containing the references that are used in Chapter 2 and Chapter 3, respectively)
- References that are used in Chapter 2 and/or Chapter 3, but not in Introduction or Discussion should not be included in the References of Introduction/Discussion.
- References should be printed after Chapter 2, after Chapter 3 and Discussion
- there should be no reference list after Introduction (all references from Introduction should be used in the reference list of the discussion)

I have created the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english,arial,twoside]{article}\usepackage[]{graphicx}\usepackage[]{color}
%\usepackage[backend=bibtex,natbib,style=authoryear,maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{citations}
\usepackage[authoryear,sectionbib, sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}


\begin{filecontents*}{bibliography_mwe.bib}
@article{ref1,
    title={ref1},
    author={ref1},
    year={1},
    institution={ref1}
}

@article{ref2,
    title={ref2},
    author={ref2},
    year={2},
    institution={ref2}
}

@article{ref3,
    title={ref3},
    author={ref3},
    year={3},
    institution={ref3}
}

@article{ref4,
    title={ref4},
    author={ref4},
    year={4},
    institution={ref4}
}

@article{ref5,
    title={ref5},
    author={ref5},
    year={5},
    institution={ref5}
}

@article{ref6,
    title={ref6},
    author={ref6},
    year={6},
    institution={ref6}
}

@article{ref7,
    title={ref7},
    author={ref7},
    year={7},
    institution={ref7}
}

@article{ref8,
    title={ref8},
    author={ref8},
    year={8},
    institution={ref8}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\section{Introduction}
bla bla bla bla bla \newline
\cite{ref1} \newline
bla bla bla bla bla \newline
\cite{ref2} \newline
bla bla bla bla bla \newline
\cite{ref3} \newline
bla bla bla bla bla \newline

\begin{filecontents*}{chap2_mwe.tex}
\section{Chapter 2}
bla bla bla bla bla \newline
\cite{ref4} \newline
bla bla bla bla bla \newline
\cite{ref5} \newline

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{bibliography_mwe}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{chap3_mwe.tex}
\section{Chapter 3}
bla bla bla bla bla \newline
\cite{ref6} \newline
bla bla bla bla bla \newline
\cite{ref7} \newline

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{bibliography_mwe}
\end{filecontents*}


\include{chap2_mwe}
\include{chap3_mwe}

\section{Discussion}

bla bla bla bla bla \newline
\cite{ref4} \newline
bla bla bla bla bla \newline
\cite{ref8} \newline

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{bibliography_mwe}

\end{document}
```

I would like to have the following output:

- Reference list of Chapter 2: ref4, ref5
- Reference list of Chapter 3: ref6, ref7
- Reference list of Introduction&Discussion: ref1, ref2, ref3, ref4, ref8.

Do you have any idea how this can work?

My idea with using `filecontents*` environments for Chapter 2 and Chapter 3, does not work, when compiling:

```
bibtex chap2_mwe.aux
bibtex chap3_mew.aux
bibtex mwe.aux
pdflatex_mwe.tex
pdflatex_mwe.tex
```

**EDIT** as proposed by @moewe: using `bibtex` and `refsection` only one bibliography is created. Maybe I am missing something here...
EDIT: works if I have used it correctly (see below)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english,arial,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}\usepackage[]{color}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography_mwe}
\usepackage{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents*}{bibliography_mwe.bib}
@article{ref1,
    title={ref1},
    author={ref1},
    year={1},
    institution={ref1}
}

@article{ref2,
    title={ref2},
    author={ref2},
    year={2},
    institution={ref2}
}

@article{ref3,
    title={ref3},
    author={ref3},
    year={3},
    institution={ref3}
}

@article{ref4,
    title={ref4},
    author={ref4},
    year={4},
    institution={ref4}
}

@article{ref5,
    title={ref5},
    author={ref5},
    year={5},
    institution={ref5}
}

@article{ref6,
    title={ref6},
    author={ref6},
    year={6},
    institution={ref6}
}

@article{ref7,
    title={ref7},
    author={ref7},
    year={7},
    institution={ref7}
}

@article{ref8,
    title={ref8},
    author={ref8},
    year={8},
    institution={ref8}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}\label{sec:int}

bla bla bla bla bla \newline
\cite{ref1} \newline
bla bla bla bla bla \newline
\cite{ref2} \newline
bla bla bla bla bla \newline
\cite{ref3} \newline
bla bla bla bla bla \newline

\begin{refsection}
\section{Chapter 2}\label{sec:2}
bla bla bla bla bla \newline
\cite{ref4} \newline
bla bla bla bla bla \newline
\cite{ref5} \newline

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}

\begin{refsection}
\section{Chapter 3}\label{sec:3}
bla bla bla bla bla \newline
\cite{ref6} \newline
bla bla bla bla bla \newline
\cite{ref7} \newline

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}

\section{Discussion}\label{sec:disc}

bla bla bla bla bla \newline
\cite{ref4} \newline
bla bla bla bla bla \newline
\cite{ref8} \newline

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: 
solution: run 
`pdflatex mwe.tex`
`bibtex mwe.aux`
`bibtex mwe1-blx.aux`
`bibtex mwe2-blx.aux`
`pdflatex mwe.tex`

Comment: It's too late for me to look into this in more detail, but out of the box `natbib` (or BibTeX in general) doesn't support multiple bibliographies, no matter if you use `\include` (and/or `filecontents`) or not. You'll need additional packages like https://ctan.org/pkg/chapterbib or https://ctan.org/pkg/bibunits, but I'm not sure if those are enough for what you want.

Comment: `biblatex` can do a lot more in that regard (but I'm not sure if what you want is easily doable with `biblatex`, either.) Possibly interesting/related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44602/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17474/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229846/35864

Comment: Thank you @moewe . At least with my MWE I am getting separate (correct) References for Chapter 2 and 3. The only problem is that Introduction&Discussion includes all used references. If there is a solution with `biblatex` that would be great, too. Looking at your links it seems, that they are dealing with slightly different question. I guess, in my case it is most tricky that the two connected sections (Introduction&Discussion) are split up by Chapter 2 and Chapter 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two approaches with `biblatex`. When you split bibliographies in `biblatex` you can choose between two ways of dividing the bibliographies

- `refsection`s keep their contents completely separated and independent.
- `refsegment`s just add a small note (similar to `keyword`) to an entry that it was cited in a certain `refsegment`. All entries are still considered together for sorting and uniqueness computations.

In practice you often won't be seeing a difference between the two approaches, but it is possible to create situations where the difference matters.

In general `refsegment`s and `refsection`s can't be split or nested. An exception is `refsection` `0` that can be split. In the `refsection` code below we use that `refsection` `0` can be split and use it for the introduction and discussion. That's the reason why we can't use automatic `refsection`s: They would produce different `refsection`s for the introduction and the discussion and there would be no way to merge them. For the `refsegment` approach that is not as much of a concern, since we can easily filter by multiple `refsegment`s.

### `refsection`

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=alphabetic, maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}\label{sec:int}
Lorem \cite{pines}
ipsum \cite{aksin}
dolor \cite{maron}

\begin{refsection}
\section{Chapter 2}\label{sec:2}
lorem \cite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \cite{worman,knuth:ct:c}

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,
  title={\refname\ of \nameref{sec:2}}]
\end{refsection}

\begin{refsection}
\section{Chapter 3}\label{sec:3}
lorem \cite{nussbaum}
ipsum \cite{geer,knuth:ct:b}

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,
  title={\refname\ of \nameref{sec:3}}]
\end{refsection}

\section{Discussion}\label{sec:disc}

dolor \cite{sigfridsson}
sit \cite{cicero}

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,
  title={\refname\ of \nameref{sec:int} and \nameref{sec:disc}}]
\end{document}
```

[image: References for chapters 2 and 3]

### `refsegment`s

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=alphabetic, refsegment=section, maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}\label{sec:int}
\newcommand*\intrefsegment{} % we'll need that later
\edef\intrefsegment{\therefsegment}
Lorem \cite{pines}
ipsum \cite{aksin}
dolor \cite{maron}

\section{Chapter 2}\label{sec:2}
lorem \cite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \cite{worman,knuth:ct:c}

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,
  title={\refname\ of \nameref{sec:2}},
  segment=\therefsegment]

\section{Chapter 3}\label{sec:3}
lorem \cite{nussbaum}
ipsum \cite{geer,knuth:ct:b}

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,
  title={\refname\ of \nameref{sec:3}},
  segment=\therefsegment]

\section{Discussion}\label{sec:disc}

dolor \cite{sigfridsson}
sit \cite{cicero}

% we remembered the segment from the introduction in \intrefsegment
\defbibfilter{intdisc}{%
     segment=\intrefsegment\space
  or segment=\therefsegment
}

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,
  title={\refname\ of \nameref{sec:int} and \nameref{sec:disc}},
  filter=intdisc]
\end{document}
```

[image: References for chapter 2 and 3]

---

The differences between the two approaches become apparent in the two Knuth citations. Since `refsection`s are independent, the two different citations `knuth:ct:b` and `knuth:ct:c` both get the same label in different sections. `refsegment`s, on the other hand, are not independent and there the labels differ.

---

While both approaches work with `backend=bibtex,`, I still recommend switching to Biber (`backend=biber,`). Especially the `refsection` solution benefits from Biber because you only have to run Biber on one file (once) and not on multiple files. In general you only have access to all `biblatex` features if you use Biber.

Comment: @tnaake Really? It does for me in both MWEs. It's just that that list is on the next page in the document, so I didn't include it in the screenshot. Did you try the *exact* same code I posted or something else? I recommend you try and get the code I posted working first, if you haven't done that already (note that you need to change nothing, the file `biblatex-examples.bib` that I used will be found automatically, since it is installed together with `biblatex`).

Comment: Sorry, @moewe. Now it worked. I did not run `bibtex mwe1-blx.aux` and `bibtex mwe2-blx.aux`. Thank you so much!

Comment: @tnaake One more reason to switch to Biber: With Biber you just run `biber mwe` and that's it.